# Toad Edge 2.1.5 - Error provided jdbc driver not suitable

Tags: mysql, toad

I am getting an error in Toad Edge 2.1.5 for the MySQL database.
[image]

For one of the databases, the same JDBC is working for another database with the same version of MySQL 8. it is giving the above error.
Kindly help me to rectify the error.
I'm using MySQL 8 Server in same machine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it worked connecting with root user. Make sure you are connecting with the same user than in the other successful connection.

In case you are trying with the same user, type this on your MySQL server console:

ALTER USER 'youruser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'yourpassword';

It's necessary for authenticating in MySQL 8.